# How to delete characters/numbers within a string based on certain positions?

Tags: r, string

I have ID's written as

```
PSA20001_USDa1_d0001
PSA20001_USDa2_d0002
PSA20001_USDa3_d0003
```

and I would like to remove just the middle part starting with a underscore,

```
_USDa1_
```

I tried

```
str_replace(data$id, pattern = "_\\w\\_", replacement = "")
```

but it wouldn't work. any help please?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` to match the `_` followed by one or more characters that are not a `_` and then an `_`, replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("_[^_]+_", "", df1$id)
#[1] "PSA20001d0001" "PSA20001d0002" "PSA20001d0003"
```

Or if it is based on position, then `substr` can also be used

```
with(df1, paste0(substr(id, 1, 8), substring(id, 16)))
```

---

Or use `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(df1$id, "_[^_]+_")
```

If we want it in the `tidyverse` flow

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(id = str_remove(id, "_[^_]+_"))
#            id
#1 PSA20001d0001
#2 PSA20001d0002
#3 PSA20001d0003
```

#### Data

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c("PSA20001_USDa1_d0001",
     "PSA20001_USDa2_d0002", "PSA20001_USDa3_d0003"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sub`:

```
data$id <- sub("_.+_", "", data$id)
```

With `str_replace` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data %>%
  mutate(id = str_replace(id, pattern = "_.+?_", replacement = ""))
```

**Output:**

```
             id
1 PSA20001d0001
2 PSA20001d0002
3 PSA20001d0003
```

**Notes:**

1. `_` matches a literal underscore
2. `.+` matches any character one or more times
3. `_` again matches a literal underscore

As noted by Tim Biegeleisen in the comments, if there are more underscores in the string, it is probably safer to make the regex lazy by using `.+?` instead of `.+`

**Data:**

```
data <- structure(list(id = c("PSA20001d0001", "PSA20001d0002", "PSA20001d0003"
)), .Names = "id", row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @irene Can you elaborate? What do you mean it doesn't work properly?

Comment: oh it works perfectly now, my bad! thank you for the help!